# Automated Number Distribution in Spreadsheets

Tags: google-sheets, automation, google-sheets-formula, spreadsheet

Beginner here!

[Here's a spreadsheet trying to show what I mean.](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/17PPBEYYcxYfSGaBE0hannY0T8YKJHmeHTensJ1_RHg0/edit?usp=sharing)

Suppose I have data for metrics in comparison to my competitors.

The metrics are sorted highest to lowest and I want to turn the names of the other companies into "Company 1, Company 2, etc." along with the order of the metrics. Myself ("Me") remains unchanged.

With every data set the competitors could be different companies, and I could be ranked in a different position. The number of competitors could range from 1-20.

Is there a way to automate the green fields in the spreadsheet so that I can just paste the data and the competitor numbering stays constant no matter where I appear in the list?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lighter Torches, I've added a sheet named "Erik" to your spreadsheet.

I've placed an array formula into two cells: G5 and J5. They are the same except for the relative cell references. Since it is an array formula, the single formula in G5 "runs" the entire data set generated in G5:H; likewise, the formula in J5 "runs" the entire data set generated in J5:K. Array formulas do not require dragging/copying to other cells.

Here is the G5 formula:

```
=ArrayFormula(QUERY(SPLIT({"Me"&"^"&IFERROR(VLOOKUP("Me",A5:B,2,FALSE),"NA");"Company "&ROW(INDIRECT("A1:A"&COUNTA(FILTER(A5:A,A5:A<>"",A5:A<>"Me"))))&"^"&SORT(FILTER(B5:B,A5:A<>"",A5:A<>"Me"),FILTER(B5:B,A5:A<>"",A5:A<>"Me"),FALSE)},"^"),"Select * Order By Col2 Desc"))
```

In your sample data, the companies are *already ordered by rank*, best to worst. But in the real world, it seems that may not always be the case. With that in mind, you'll notice that I moved your top performer to the bottom in the second data set. I've written the formulas to account for this (i.e., they will order the companies in the correct order whether they were originally in the correct order or not).

Also, if "Me" for some reason doesn't appear in a raw-data list at all, it still shows up, unranked, at the top of the generated list. Again, I tried to account for real-world what-ifs in the formula.

Finally, I added a sheet-wide custom Conditional Formatting rule that applies **bold** to any occurrence of the word "**Me**," since it seemed you were doing that manually. As such, you can type the sole word "Me" in *any* cell in the sheet, and it will automatically be formatted **bold**. You can see this rule by selecting **Format > Conditional Formatting** from the menu, then clicking on the rule you see in the window that appears.

Comment: You're a star, Erik! Works like a charm. Thanks a million!

Comment: It was a fun puzzle. Glad it was helpful.